# Python: Preserve last line in console for specific output

Tags: python, console, stdout

I have a program that does lots of printing. For UX, I want to have the line at the bottom of the console screen always display the same piece of information - a summary of how many jobs are done, and how many remain `X done, Y remaining` (X and Y are constantly changing throughout the program's runtime).

I tried using `curses`, however, I only need to control one line and I could not find a way to limit `curses`'s screen scope.

I also tried using blessings:

```
with t.location(0, t.height - 1):
    print 'This is at the bottom.'
```

but it only worked when there wasn't enough stdout to reach the last line in the console.

I am using python 2.7

Comment: Is this python 2?

Comment: @Sky Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def print_with_fixed_bottom(message):
    fixed = 'This is at the bottom.'
    print '\r{: <{width}}\n{}'.format(message, fixed, width=len(fixed)), # comma is important
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Yes, it prints at the bottom, but when more output comes, the new output is printed under the message. What I want is that it is at the bottom of the screen and no other output overrides it.

Comment: @Sky, your message is one line or multiline?

Comment: It's just one line.

Comment: @Sky, but I've tested and it works in my env. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Linux

Comment: @Sky, I have no opportunity to test on linux, but it has to work. Solution is based on [`"\r"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) control char, which put cursor on the start of current line. Trailing comma let python to not add `"\n"` character after printed message.

Comment: @Sky, could you try to launch [this](https://repl.it/repls/WorrisomeFondExperiments) code in your console and share output?